# writing input to a python script via bash script

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script that requires input from the user, but since i need to run this around 300 times, I was looking for a way to feed the input via bash code. My python code is in the form

```
import sys
inFile = eval(raw_input(sys.argv[1]))
outFile1 = eval(raw_input(sys.argv[2]))
finalfit = eval(raw_input(sys.argv[3]))
```

and then I go on doing my thing.

In the bash script i just wrote

```
python filename.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

but when I try to run this, it just retuns a line with arg1, and if i hit enter, it gives me an error in the form

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "narrowtry.py", line 69, in 
>     inFile = eval(raw_input(sys.argv[1]))
>
> File "", line 0
>
> ^
>    SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

since the input shoud be a string, i tried using

Comment: Don't use `eval`! Especially for user input. [It's dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081082/5067311)

Comment: If those `arg`s are your input, you don't even need `raw_input`; just set `inFile = sys.argv[1]` etc.

Comment: @AndrasDeak look closely - arg1 arg2 arg3 are just used as prompts in `raw_input`; it is the three lines that are read from `sys.stdin` that are important.

Comment: @Błotosmętek looking at the code quality, I'm fairly sure OP meant those args to be the input. That's why "pressing enter" led to an error: the inputs were empty strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `eval` to parse user input! It could do dangerous things.

With that said, take a look at what your code is doing, in interpreter mode:

```
>>> eval(raw_input('arg1'))
arg1           # press enter here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>>>
```

`sys.argv[1]` already contains `arg1`. You are then passing this as a parameter to the `raw_input` function, which will then expect user input. Since you pass nothing, `eval` receives only a newline character, and throws an error.

You fix this by doing:

```
inFile = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: I'd suggest against putting `eval` warnings *at the end*: those should be huge red blinking danger signs. Especially considering the number of users who copy-paste code from SO with no second thoughts (or first ones for that matter).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Good advice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `eval`! Especially for user input. [It's dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081082/5067311).

If those `arg`s are your input, you don't even need `raw_input`; just set `inFile = sys.argv[1]` etc.

But you should think it through what the original [was trying to do](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) with you args (and why `eval` was completely unnecessary, even wrong). You'll run into this again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass the arguments to `stdin` of the Python script, not pass them as command-line arguments as you have now.  In Bash you can do this:

```
python filename.py <<< arg1 arg2 arg3
```